# Почему не работает короткий путь в WPF?

Tags: wpf, .net

Это мой первый проект в WPF. Не могу понять, почему не работает короткий путь к изображению. Есть **Control Template** для **Button**

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="Button" x:Key="buttonTemplate">
    <Grid x:Name="Buttons">
        <Border x:Name="Btns">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=Img}" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="45" Width="45" Stretch="Fill" Margin="10, 0, 0, 0"/>
                <Label Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Background="Transparent"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="17" Margin="10, 0, 0, 0" Foreground="White">
                </Label>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Когда я использую этот шаблон, мне придется использовать полный путь к изображению.

```
<Button Template="{StaticResource buttonTemplate}" Content="Кітап қосу" Command="{Binding OpenAddBookPage}">
    <Button.Resources>
        <ImageSource x:Key="Img">
            C:\Users\user\source\repos\LeskhanEmployee\Employee\View\Resourses\Icons\add-book.png
        </ImageSource>
    </Button.Resources>
</Button>
```

Попробовал использовать:

> ..\Resourses\Icons\add-book.png
>
> \Resourses\Icons\add-book.png
>
> /Resourses/Icons/add-book.png
>
> ../Resourses/Icons/add-book.png

Выдает ошибку

> Не удается найти ресурс "Resourses\Icons\add-book.png"

Подскажите пожалуйста, как написать правильно чтобы работал короткий путь?

На всякий пожар оставлю иерархию:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пишу на .NET 5

Comment: У вас же Resourses в View папке, а значит и в пути это должно быть. Также проверьте, чтоб у изображений было указано "Ресурс" в свойствах.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо, помогло)